# Passing only Date from controller through DateTime Object. Trying Multiple ways bind Time alongwith

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime, model-view-controller

My `.cs` file contains this.

[image]

Model also contains the same `datatype`

while filling data in form i get the value as

[image]

In SQL i've kept datatype as `date` and in model it is necessary to keep DateTime.

I tried `ParseExact()`, `.Date`, etc but everything ultimately turns out along with time.

[image]

Can anyone please help? 
I tried many solutions found in this site related to this question but didn't get any help.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Unlike VB, in C# there is no separate Type for `Date` and `Time`. Its always `DateTime`. Its on frontend that you have to decorate with formats to show only `Date` or `Time`.

Comment: Yes i know that, but i'm unable to sort that out with the possible solutions. I'm trying with the answer by @Arijit Mukherjee

Comment: if you are using `TextBoxFor()` then only that will work else in case of `EditorFor()` you need to do it in the model

Comment: You also need to reconfigure the `$.validator` if you want to validate dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your Model

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

and in the .cshtml

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastPaymentDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

Comment: The 2 attributes are pointless if using `TextBoxFor()`. Those are only respected when using `EditorFor()`.

Comment: Yes I agree but I didnt knew what the OP is using in her Views, so just to be on the safer side.

Comment: with EditorFor() it is binding another calender within view. @ArijitMukherjee

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: That is because the `[DataType]` attribute generates the browsers HTML 5 datepicker

Comment: And if you use that attribute then the `DataFormatString` must be `yyyy-MM-dd` (ISO format)

Comment: Yes you are right @StephenMuecke , and i changed it to `TextBoxFor` and now it is working for me @ArijitMukherjee, Thank you so much both of you for your Help. :)